# running unity3d game on linux minimal

Tags: xorg, xserver, ubuntu-minimal, unity3d

**Problem:**
I created a unity game to work as an infotainment system for a car. Since the "game" will display on the dashboard of a car I want it to boot as fast as possible, with no greeter or reference to the underlying OS. Just a simple boot straight to the game.

In order to do this, I installed on an SSD the latest minimal ubuntu version. **I understand I have to install some additional packages or start some graphic modes to get my game going but I still didn't figure out which they are...** Can you help me?

**What I did:**
**1**: In linux runt LDD on all executable files I could find:

```
game.x86_64
game_Data/Plugins/x86_64/ScreenSelector.so
game_Data/Mono/x86_64/libMonoPosixHelper.so
game_Data/Mono/x86_64/libmono.so
```

Of these files only ScreenSelector.so made reference to libs that I didn't have:

```
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0
```

So I installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
```

**2:** I run the game:
./game.x86_64
it prints:

```
Set current directory to /home/crx/game
Found path: /home/crx/game/game.x86_64
Mono path[0] = '/home/crx/game/game_Data/Managed'
Mono config path = '/home/crx/game/game_Data/Mono/etc'
Preloaded 'ScreenSelector.so'
Logging to /home/crx/.config/unity3d/DefaultCompany/GAME/Player.log
```

and it stays like that until I Ctrl+Z it.

when I open Player.log it just has inside the following:

```
Desktop is 0 x 0 @ 0 Hz
```

So I runt glxinfo and it said "unable to open display"

So then decided to instal X server:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-dummy xserver-xorg-input-void 
xserver-xorg-core xinit x11-xserver-utils xorg
```

but it still didnt work...

And when I try to run directly screenselector.so it just prints
CORE DUMP!!!!!!!!

I believe I must start X with xinit or something and while the server is up run the game. But is that it? and if so... how can I do it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was missing... In order to run the game one only needs to run and X session specifying the location of the game executable.

In my case:

```
sudo xinit ~/game/game.x86_64
```

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.

Apparently, the only things Unity3d requires in order for a game to be runt in ubuntu minimal is:

```
gtk
x server
```

Comment: Also, on linux minimal you have to make sure to install xserver-xorg-input-evdev in order to get input devices properly